# Guess and Prove by induction a formula for the $n$-th element in a sequence $b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction

So I've been given a sequence.

The sequence $b_0,b_1,b_2$, ... is defined as follows:

$b_0 = 0$, $b_1 = 1/2$, and for integers $n \ge 2$, $b_n = \sqrt{b_{n-1}b_{n-2}} + \frac{3n}{2} - 1.$

My calculations for the first 5 values of n:
$b_0 = 0, 
b_1 = 0.5,
b_2 = 2,
b_3 = 4.5,
b_4 = 8,
b_5 = 12.5$

from these values I've seen a pattern for any $n \ge 0$ and have been asked to guess a formula to produce them.

Namely that  $n^2/2$ will give me all those values above and more,

Additionally I'm asked for
Proof by induction that the guess (in my case $n^2/2$) 
is true for all $n \ge 0$

Below is some of my scratch work attempting to start the proof, not part of the question simply trying to show my thinking a bit:

So far I've got $b_{k+1} = \frac{(k+1)^2}{2}$

so $b_k + b_1$ would be $\frac{k^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$

Lost on where to go next.

Comment: I don’t understand: what should be true about $n^2/2$?

Comment: What do you mean $n^2/2$ is true? $n^2/2$ is a real number (assuming real $n$), but how can a real number be true or false?

Comment: Do you mean $n^2 | 2$? Or $2|n^2$?

Comment: I mean n is true insofar as it satisfies or produces the sequence I tried to guess the formula for.

Comment: Wait... What? What do you mean by $n$ is true? Can you provide the direct statement of the question?

Comment: @J2R5M3 I'm so confused.

Comment: sorry, trying to edit and clear things up, I'm confused to which doesn't help

Comment: You have an extremely misleading title. Suggested edit.

Comment: You want to prove that for all $n, b_n = n^2/2$, right?

Comment: $b_{k+1} = \sqrt{b_kb_{k-1}}+ \frac{3k}{2} -1$, not $b_k+b_1$. Proceed by strong induction.

Comment: @J2R5M3: If you edit your post to write out what Naman Kumar suggested (the actual recursion, not the strange $b_k+b_1$ you put in), and attempt to evaluate it, I will vote to reopen your post.

Comment: So via induction if $b_{n-1} = \frac{(n-1)^2}2$ and $b_n=\frac{n^2}2$, then you need to prove: $b_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)^2}2\frac{n^2}2} + \frac {3(n+1)}2 - 1= (n+1)^2$.  If you can do that you are done.

Comment: @BrianTung Do these edits clear things up enough to warrant a reopen?

Comment: I've voted to reopen, even though you didn't make the edit I specifically suggested, because I think you might need people to explain why that edit should be made.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are trying to prove that

> if $b_0=0$, $b_1=1/2$ and $b_n=\sqrt{b_{n-1}b_{n-2}}+\frac{3n}{2}-1$, for $n\ge2$, then $b_n=n^2/2$, for all $n\ge0$.

This is true for $n=0$ and $n=1$. Suppose it is for all $m<n$, where $n\ge2$. Then
$$
b_n=\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)^2}{2}\frac{(n-2)^2}{2}}+\frac{3n}{2}-1
$$
Can you finish?